# jscrollpane reinitialise not working

Tags: php, jquery, jscrollpane

Please follow the codes below with details about my jscrollpane which is not reinitialising .The comment will help you to understand the code.

```
//in the main php file styles - 

    live-demo {width: 550px;height:500px;overflow: auto; }

//under script tag

    var ms_js = jQuery.noConflict();        
    ms_js(function(){   
    ms_js('#live-demo').My_func
    ({ 
      id:'2211155996',...... // all params for this function call located in antoher js file 
    });

//in the external js file - 

    (function($) { 
    $.fn.My_func = function(options) {
    ...all data getting codes here by ajax which outputs data to #live-demo...
    ...

    //also here have jscrollpane declaration for live-demo div

    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(function(){ jQuery('#live-demo'+o.show_suffixs+'').jScrollPane(); });

    })(jQuery);

//in the main php file again under script tag

    ms_js("#msfb_clickbtn").click(function(){ 
    var container = ms_js('#live-demo');
    var api = container.data('jsp');    

    ms_js('#live-demo').My_func({ 
    id:'2211155996',...//call again for data as above
    });

    api.reinitialise();

    });

//script ends

//this button click call to reaload ajax data again as above script does

    input id="msfb_clickbtn" type="button" value="test"
```

but on button click i see data loaded in live-demo div but scroll pane is not showing

Comment: is jscrollpane called before or after the content is loaded in #live-demo. Make sure the ajax call completes before initializing it. By reading your code, it's hard to understand. Could you provide a fiddle (working example)

Comment: You see My_func which located in external js file which i call after button click and it provides all data by ajax.then i call api.reinitialise so how to overcome problems ? For code privacy cant share code in jsfiddle now